# If stocks are products, and inflation makes the price of products go up, then why don't stocks benefit from inflation?

Tags: stocks, inflation

Inflation makes my money worth less, but stocks aren't money: They're a product that's worth money. If inflation makes prices rise, then does it follow that inflation will also increase the value of my stocks?

Comment: Depends on your definition of value, doesn't it?  Assuming that everything else is constant (which isn't going to happen, of course), the price of stocks will go up by the amount of inflation.  But if you sell the stock, you will be able to buy exactly the same goods & services with that larger amount of money.

Comment: It might raise the *price* of the stock. But if it does so exactly in line with the rise in prices of everything else, then the *value* of the stock hasn't changed.

Comment: Inflation doesn't *cause* prices to rise though; it's a measure of how much prices *have risen* in the face of a money supply that has increased faster than the supply of items that can be purchased with that money.

Comment: @chepner: No, you're confusing inflation, which is an increase in the money supply, with the effects of supply & demand.  Prices can change without any inflation, for instance the seasonal change in the price of fruit.  At the other extreme, a government  (Weimar Germany, Venezuela, &c) can try to cure its economic problems by just printing money.  The resulting inflation increases prices, without any change in supply & demand.

Comment: By what definition is corporate stock a product?

Comment: @jamesqf The increase in the money supply is what causes the increase in prices. It's *a* way for prices to increase: the supply of money can outstrips the demand for goods, or the demand for goods can outstrip the supply of money. Both will drive prices up.

Comment: @chepner: If you measure the prices by some external standard, they stay the same.  It's the money that's worth less than it used to be. (Not worthless - the space is important :-))  Say you're in Venezuela, and see the price of everything in bolivars increasing astronomically.  But if you look at the prices in US dollars, or Euros, they haven't changed much.

Comment: Inflation doesn't "make" prices go up any more than birthdays make you older. Inflating is simply the measurement of the increase in prices of products. If you choose to define stocks as products then you can measure the inflation of stock prices. Wage inflation, CPI, RPI, PPI, gdp deflator don't have to line up, and neither does stock inflation.

Comment: @Corvus: But you've still go things backwards.  Prices going up isn't the cause of inflation, it's a consequence of it.  Inflation is the decrease in the value of money.  Again, compare prices in an inflated currency vs prices in a stable one.

Comment: @jamesqf most definitions I've been able to find define inflation as some variation of "the increase in the price of goods and services over time". Some of them define it as "the increase in the price of goods and services over time OR the increase in the supply of money", but as far as I can tell, that is not a common definition. Therefore - Prices going up IS inflation. Increase in money supply can CAUSE inflation. Corvus and Chepner are correct.

Comment: @BeB00: Then those definitions are wrong :-)  It's an all-too-common misunderstanding.  Prices going up is usually just a matter of supply & demand: why do gas prices go up, or Silicon Valley real estate prices?  Supply & demand, not inflation.  Or why has the price of consumer electronics historically gone down,  deflation?

Comment: @jamesqf I dont think you, random internet person, can just say "all of these official sources (like forbes, IMF, cambridge dictionary, etc) are wrong" without any sources of your own. Your argument also doesn't address what you're trying to argue. As many above have said, you're talking about *causes* of inflation. You're asking "why" inflation happens, but what we're talking about is what inflation *is*, and what inflation *is* is prices of things generally going up. Different things can cause inflation (i.e. increase in the money supply can cause prices to go up).

Comment: @BeB00: Not me, random internet person, economics texts.  There is, I believe, a StackExchange economics site where you might get better answers.

Comment: @jamesqf maybe you could point to one or two of those economic texts? here are some of my sources: https://www.bls.gov/opub/mlr/1981/09/art2full.pdf https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/inflation https://www.forbes.com/advisor/investing/what-is-inflation/ https://www.thebalance.com/what-is-inflation-357610 There are definitely some who say that its both prices increasing and money supply increasing, but your argument of "it's definitely only money supply increasing" seems far from the mainstream. Perhaps you could also get better answers from Economics Stackexchange?

Comment: @jamesqf you may be interested in this discussion (https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9767/inflation-without-increase-in-money-supply/9768#9768) which discusses how the price of goods can increase without an increase in the money supply

Comment: @BeB00: That SE link seems to support what I'm saying, no?  Though adding a few technical things like velocity of money, which I admit I don't understand.  Again, look at the many, many cases where the price of some things increases (or sometimes decreases), without any (apparent) change in the money.  For instance, there have been many news stories about the price of cars increasing.  Is it inflation, or supply and demand at work: limited production of new cars due to a shortage of chips &c?

Comment: @jamesqf That answer is just showing how the price of things generally can increase without an increase in the money supply. I don't think it makes any determination on what does and doesnt count as inflation (as mentioned in the first paragraph of the answer). Notice that it's specifically talking about *general* price levels, not the price of some specific goods (like cars)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Stocks are not products, they are shares of companies. If the companies are expected to perform well, stock prices are high. If they are expected to perform bad, stock prices are low. If a company was expected to perform well but is now expected to perform worse, the stock price will fall.

This is where inflation can come in. While inflation is typically measured on the level of consumer goods ("consumer price index"), the price of raw materials and labor tends to increase as well. This increases the production costs of companies. Their earnings will only increase if they are able to increase the price of their products to match the increase in cost. The ability to push higher prices to the customers can vary a lot between companies.

Answer (score 32):

Stocks aren't products, they are assets.

In either case their prices DO tend to go up with inflation just like any other asset. However, I wouldn't say they benefit from this any more than owning any other asset. For example: if the stock price hypothetically doubled in price because of inflation and the dollar was worth half as much, did you really benefit?

Caveat: Also just like other assets, inflation does not equally affect all stocks. So your results will vary based on the individual companies or industries.

Comment: I think they would 'benefit' more from inflation than some other asset classes - e.g. Bonds.

Comment: +1 Across a broad base of companies, I would expect stock prices to be more-or-less neutral to the effects of moderate inflation.

Comment: "For example: if the stock price hypothetically doubled in price because of inflation and the dollar was worth half as much, did you really benefit?"

You definitely wouldn't benefit! You'd pay capital gains taxes of around 1/3 of the doubling in price, leaving you worse off than before. The more the inflation, the worse it would be.

Answer (score 6):

Some companies can react to inflation by raising their prices but many cannot, especially those that compete in a global market where others don't have to raise prices due to inflation.

Inflation erodes purchasing power since wages do not keep up with inflation, consumers purchases fewer goods.  Many companies cannot raise prices to offset their increased costs and therefore they have to sacrifice profit in an attempt to maintain sales and avoid a significant decline in profit.  It's a no win situation and share price tends to decline.

To fight inflation, the Fed raises rates and this too adds to corporate costs. Dividends do not keep up with inflation, further exacerbating this cycle - dividend stocks suffer - as well as cyclical stocks.

It's a far more complex problem than just saying that share price will increase because company products are higher priced.

Answer (score 4):

On the whole, averaged across all stocks and smoothing out over recessions, they do.

But shares in individual companies are another matter.  The value of the shares in any one company depends on the fortunes of that company, and can go up or down independently of anything else.  The effect of inflation can get lost in the noise.

Answer (score 3):

### Stock Value is Future Profits - By Definition

In theory, the stock price is exactly equal to the sum of all future profits, discounted by time (a dollar today is worth more than a dollar 10 days from now, because I can spend it today).

Things are complicated in the real world because no one can accurately predict future profits. Everyone in the markets tries their best, and the stock price you see on the ticker is everyone's estimates averaged together.

### Future Profit is in Future Dollars

Stocks don't necessarily feel inflationary pressures, because the expected ***value*** of future profits doesn't necessarily change.

A company's total ***value*** is the same, whether you discuss it in dollars or yen. But the number you use in your discussion is very different. Inflation is just treating future dollars like a foreign currency.

### Except...

If inflation impacts the underlying profitability of the company, then the stock value should change. If inflation leads to labor or material shortages, then obviously you can say that inflation has effected the stock price.

But in general, stock prices aren't negatively impacted by inflation.

Answer (score 1):

> If inflation makes prices rise, then does it follow that inflation
> will also increase the value of my stocks?

No it does not. Will the company that you have invested perform better or worse in a high inflation environment? This COVID related inflation, is pushing the United States into a inflation level that we haven't seen in 30 years. The question is how long will this spike last. That 1990 spike was during the buildup to the first gulf war. The recession didn't last long. How long will this one last?

How will your investment perform? Nobody knows. The way they perform could depend on their sector of the economy, and how consumers and other industries view their products.

Remember investing in stocks is not like putting your money in a bank. You can lose money.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of excellent answers, but you can cut through a lot of the complications. Here are my two answers. Which one is correct depends on which specific definition of inflation you are using.

The answers can be summarized as: "They do benefit, because rising stock prices is exactly the same as inflation" and "They don't because we define it away".

## They Do

In fact, we have had dramatic inflation in the stock market for several decades, and stocks benefited from it (but see the third section below about that part).

Inflation is the increase in prices for the same underlying items. Notably, inflation is not evenly distributed across all markets - you may see dramatic housing inflation or inflation in medical costs, and no inflation at all in, say, groceries. That's the situation we had for several decades.

If you look at it this way, inflation in the stock market is simply another word for a rising stock market.

Also, the mechanism behind rising stock prices is exactly the same mechanism as behind inflation in other markets: more people have money available, and are interested in, buying stocks than people willing to sell.

**Update**: after discussing this with @quid in the comments below, there is a somewhat different way of looking at stocks. One can reasonable view them (in this context, not generally) not as a share of a company, but as an entitlement to a fraction of future earnings of that company. In that view, inflation would not be simply the increase in stock price, but rather the increase in the price/earnings ratio.

It does not fundamentally change my answer, because P/E ratios have also dramatically increased over the last several decades.

## They Don't

Despite what I said above, one can also reasonably argue that stocks don't benefit from inflation.

This is because when we talk about inflation, we usually talk about a specific *type* of inflation: the CPI, or Consumer Price Index. However, the CPI does not measure the prices of everything; it only looks at a basket of goods that consumers typically buy. Stocks are excluded (as well as a lot of other things).

Which of these two answers is correct depends on exactly which definition of inflation you are using.

## The question itself is problematic

You asked why stocks don't "benefit" from inflation. The question itself is problematic, because you have to define what you mean by "benefit". I am assuming that you are talking about rising stock prices, since that is generally considered a positive, whether or not that's justified.

That's indeed a benefit for anybody who owns stock (really, just for anybody who wants to sell it), but it is the opposite for somebody who wants to buy stocks.

Comment: ‘Inflation is the increase in prices for the same underlying items.’ Picking on Apple, Apples Gross Revenue and Net Income (and cash flow) on gross terms and on per share terms are up dramatically over the last decade.  One share of Apple common stock is certainly not the same “underlying item” as it was 10 years ago.  Sure, there has been multiple expansion (I’m sure apples PE is higher now than 10 years ago) but to say the rise in share price of Apple is due to inflation is nowhere near accurate.

Comment: @quid You are right, that does play a small role in the increase in stock price. However, there are two problems. First, companies like Apple or Google are extreme outliers, and for every Apple, there is a Kodak, too. You should better look to more run-of-the-mill companies like Caterpillar, Boeing, Second, the P/E ratio tries to capture exactly this issue. If you were right, the P/E ratios today should be roughly the same as 1980. Still, I did neglect this issue (deliberately, to keep the explanation simpler).

Comment: Multiple expansion has occurred, sure.  That is not inflation, that’s increased market participation and greater risk acceptance. And for whatever it’s worth I’m not your down voter, though this answer has problems.  Stock is a part of a company, the company is not the same as it was X years ago.  If a banana rises in price from $0.10 to $0.20 that’s inflation because the banana is the same.

Comment: @quid The more I think about it, the more I disagree. This is because a share that somebody bought 20 years ago is indistinguishable from a share that somebody bought yesterday. I'm also not sure what you mean by "expansion".

Comment: Expansion means expansion.  PE multiples are up generally over the market, earnings multiples have expanded; there are a lot of theories as to why, increased money supply, lower interest rates, more market participants, etc.  A banana is a banana.  The thing you’re buying is the banana.  A share of stock is a 1/X share of a company.  The X doesn’t even stay static and what you’re buying is the future cash flows of the company.  To say a share of stock has risen because of inflation is to misunderstand inflation and the fact that a share of stock is not like a banana.  Good luck.

Comment: And hell, if the average price of a banana rises but the average size of a banana also increased that wouldn’t be inflation.  Inflation is a very complex thing, to distill it down to “higher price” is to totally misunderstand it.

Comment: @quid That's exactly my point. If the average size of the banana increased, it is very distinguishable from the one you bought 20 years ago; it's a different object. A share of stock is not just indistinguishable, but it's the actual same item.

Comment: @quid - indeed, PE multiples are up generally over the market. That's the point. Even accepting your theory that stocks today aren't the same as 20 years ago because the company expanded, one would have to value that share as an entitlement to future earnings. And when the P/E ration goes up, as we agree it does, then there still was inflation on the stock price by that measure.

Comment: Because the stock certificate doesn’t matter, what you’re buying changed because the company changed just like the average banana got bigger.  Like I said, good luck!

Comment: @quid The certificate is only a symbol. What you buy is actually the company itself (or rather, a certain percentage of it). If you bought a share in 1980 and are still holding that share, it still represents the same fraction of the same company (except for stock buybacks and stock issuance).

Comment: Exactly the point, except for stock buybacks and stock issuance, and a nearly infinite number of changes to the business and market dynamics, while inflation and inflation related price change is nothing more than loss of value of the currency. I’m done now. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple really... Inflation reduces confidence in the stability of the market. If investors lose confidence, stocks tend to lose value or stagnate at best. Then again, I never studied economics and don't invest in the market myself. But this seems like a common-sense issue, not requiring a deep dive into the science of world markets.

Comment: In practice, the opposite is true. During inflationary periods, stocks tend to go up more, rather than less. This happens because money (cash, bank accounts etc.) loses value, so people want to get out of such a money-losing investment. But you have to do something else with that money, and that means, stocks, real estate and the like. That tends to feed inflation further, creating a vicious cycle. It's more complex because a high interest rate can compensate for that, and central banks often raise interest rates to break this vicious cycle.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned above, stocks are claims on the net assets of a business.  They are not a product.

From research, dividends tend to move on a lagged basis with inflation.  They tend to run about six months behind changes due to inflation.  They also tend to move about one-to-one with inflation over time.  A three percent increase in inflation tends to result in a three percent dividend increase.

Because wages also move one-to-one with inflation, wage-related costs go up as well.

How a specific firm is impacted by inflation depends in part on its debt structure.  A firm with a three percent fixed rate date due in twenty years makes bank in a six percent inflation environment, all other things being equal.

For the shareholders to get extra profit, the firm has to be able to pass on increases in costs and demanded profits.  That is not always the case.

A firm whose primary expense is salaries and interest that holds a lot of variable rate debt will see its costs rise at least as fast as inflation.

Firms in perfectly competitive markets where cost increases cannot be passed on will see a reduction in capacity and quite possibly in the number of firms.  High costs firms may shutter their doors.

Finally, high inflation carries an extra information cost.  If you saw your firm had a large increase in sales, it could be because the price of your goods did not rise enough and so became cheap by comparison.  It could also be due to a change in preference for your products over others due to features and so forth.  Do they like your new features or are you mispriced?

One calls for a simple price change.  The other requires engineers to look at the products, possibly at high expense.  Inflation adds noise and provides nothing in exchange.  That can make a firm less valuable.

The inflation hedge is with the dividend.  It is not with the price.  Inflation can reduce or increase prices.

Comment: Generally speaking, wages do *not* actually rise in tandem with inflation. In fact, since the 1970s, wages have been rising substantially slower than inflation, especially for low-wage workers.

Answer (score -1):

The top rated answer is problematic to me.

First, all companies borrow money to operate. That means they are on debt. If money becomes worth less, they actually pay less on their debt! On the other hand, CPI (the inflation that you actually feel) indicates the average price of a basket of selected goods. If CPI goes up, that means the companies are charging you more than before, and that is profit!

Second, Manziel says something like "the price of ... labor tends to increase ..." Do you really believe in that? Employees' wages and salaries are quite fixed, or rigid. Look at how much the minimum wage in the states has increased over the past decades. Do you think it catches up with the inflation rate? NO!

Finally, what do you do when you realize that your money is being worth less over time? You tend to spend it right? You are worried that today's 1 buck becomes 80 cents tomorrow right? There you go. The money that consumers' spend is, PROFIT! at a HIGHER price!